# Are the following inequalities the same?

Tags: calculus

> I have the following question - are the terms
>   $$\frac{(x-1)}{x} < \ln x < x-1$$
>   (where x>1) and
>   $$\frac{x}{1+x}\lt\ln{(1+{x})}\lt{x}$$
>   (and where x>0), the same?

Comment: They make sense in different domains so no.

Comment: In fact, starting from $\ln x<x-1$, you can get $\frac{x-1}x<\ln x$, by substituting $x\to\frac1x$. So all four inequalities are, in a sense, "the same." (And it's not hard to manipulate the bottom-right one into another useful inequality, $e^x>x+1$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure just replace each $x$ in the first inequality with $1+x$. Provided that $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: You can let  $x=1+t$.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Sure - ta muchly!